# Swift - Timer #selector doesn't work with other controller method

Tags: ios, swift, timer, selector

I try to access a method from MainViewController in AppDelegate with Timer #selector. But it is giving me an error: "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

In my AppDelegate, i have a timer;

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        MainViewController().test() //this line prints successful!

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(MainViewController.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

In my MainViewController;

```
func test() {
   print("successful!")
}
```

---

When i move that function to AppDelegate, it works as `#selector(self.test)`

Is it unachievable or did i miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, add your `MainViewController` as var in your `AppDelegate`, then you can use it as target of your `scheduledTimer` and as `#selector` you must pass the `test`

```
var controller = MainViewController()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: controller, selector: #selector(ViewController.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    return true
}
```

I hope this helps you, It works

Comment: Thanks!  `_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: MainViewController(), selector: #selector(MainViewController.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

Comment: OK, you find your own way!, its nice help

Answer (score 0):

This could be a convenient way to achieve what you are trying:

```
class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let view = MainViewController()
    view.setupTimer()
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {
var timer: Timer!
func test(sender: NSTimer!) {
    /* code */
}

func setupTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval: 5.0, target: controller, selector: #selector(test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The target is the one that has to have the method per se, in this case the app delegate doesn't have a method `test` and will crash. It would work correctly by doing something around the lines of:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let mainVC = MainViewController()

        _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: mainVC, selector: #selector(MainViewController.test), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}
```

Doing it that way, you're telling the timer that the selector it has to call is in that specific instance of the MainViewController